# Does fxcop checks all the rules?

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, fxcop

Does FxCop check all standard code rules. I feel its only checks what ever its written. I would not check what is not written. Like some functions does not have exception handling that things fxcop not able to tell. So do any other tool or trick to achieve this kind of analysis?

Best regards,
Subodh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to really answer this question.  I think what you're asking is "can FXCop check for code that has *not* been written."  The answer is yes, but only if the rule is written that way.

For example, if you have a variable that implements IDisposable, FxCop will check to ensure that Dispose is called on that object.  If not, it will raise a warning.

It really can't check to see if you included exception handling, because there are (many) valid times that you don't want to do exception handling in a given method, as it will be handled upstream.